# In Android, is there a way to get the flash(SD card) access statistics?

Tags: android, statistics

I want to do some statistics monitor work. Now I know I can monitor the WIFI speed, mobile network speed, CPU instruction per second , CPU utilization, memory(RAM) usage, LCD brightness and etc.. But I have searched a lot and I do not think there is a way to monitor the flash memory or sd card access statistics(e.g., transfer size in one second). Does anyone know? I think such statistics is very important for some research such as power management.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take some data in your app and write it to the SD card.  Pick a good amount, like at least a few megs.  Time it.  Then read it back, and time that operation, too.  Do some math and wind up with the statistics you need.

Comment: Hi Chris,  thanks for your reply. But I do not think it works to my purpose. I am not measuring the speed of the flash or sd card. I am trying to detect different application's requirements on the memory access.:>

Comment: Unfortunately the system doesn't keep track of that for you.  SD card performance really is a function of the SD card, not the OS, I don't understand why you might expect Android to keep stats about that for you.  If SD card performance is a problem, go buy a class-10 card or something.

Comment: Yes. I understand what you mean. I am a student and this is for the research purpose(power management). Thanks though:>